# Lumen API with OAuth, Guzzle get/post method

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, guzzle, lumen

I'm building a Lumen API with OAuth2 authentication, i followed this tutorial : http://esbenp.github.io/2015/05/26/lumen-web-api-oauth-2-authentication/ but i'm getting an error : 
 `"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in      C:\Users\user\Desktop\api\lumen\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlMultiHandler.php on line 99"`
Guzzle's post method ( and get method too) doesn't work for me

```
$app->get('api', function() use ($app) {
$client   = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('localhost:8000/api/hello');
return $response;
});

$app->get('api/hello', function() use ($app) {
return "Hello";
});
```

get me same errors

Comment: Try hitting `localhost:8000/api/hello` with your browser and see what happens.  It would appear as though something there isn't returning a response or is taking longer than it should to create one.

Comment: When i hit `localhost:8000/api/hello` with my browser it works, i get "Hello" but i need to get a response from localhost:8000/api/hello by hitting just localhost:8000/api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem :

POST and GET requests from my API to my API don't work because I was using

```
php artisan serve
```

so requests from localhost:8000/api on localhost:8000/api/hello didn't work but GET requests from localhost:8000/api on http://www.google.com/ did.

Example :

```
$app->get('api', function() use ($app) {
$client   = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('http://www.google.com/');
return $response;
});
```

I had to deploy my Lumen API directly on localhost in www/ folder ( C:\wamp\www on windows or /var/www/html/ on linux )

```
$app->get('api', function() use ($app) {
$client   = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('localhost/api/hello');
return $response;
});

$app->get('api/hello', function() use ($app) {
return "Hello";
});
```

And now it works.

For those who don't know how to deploy your Lumen API on localhost (or your server ) : 
My Lumen project is located in C:\wamp\www\api
Create a .htaccess in project root so its path is C:\wamp\www\api\.htaccess
with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Rename C:\wamp\www\api\server.php by C:\wamp\www\api\index.php 
In your C:\wamp\www\api\public\index.php
change

```
$app->run();
```

with

```
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->run($request);
```

Don't forget to activate mod_rewrite !